# ML.NET - how to reverse mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey using stored model

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am using a ML.Net model that uses the MapValueToKey transformation in the pipleline. After training the model, I save it.

At run-time, I load the saved model and make a prediction. This works OK, but I only get the Value (integer). How can I extract the Keys (string values) that match the predicted Values, using the model loaded from the stored file (I know the mapping is included in the stored model because I can see it if I print the Confusion Matrix).

Example code is below, showing the main elements of my problem:

```
//Note: this.AllData is preloaded:  IDataView AllData

        //Create the PipeLine - Mapping Treatment Name to a Label as needed by the Multiclass Classification model
        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "Label", nameof(TreatmentObservation.NextTreatmentName))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "roadclass", inputColumnName: nameof(TreatmentObservation.RoadClass)))
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(outputColumnName: "surf_mat", inputColumnName: nameof(TreatmentObservation.SurfMaterial)))                                                       
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "roadclass", nameof(TreatmentObservation.Rut85th), nameof(TreatmentObservation.Naasra85th)));

        //Create a LightGBM Trainer
        IEstimator<ITransformer> trainer = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LightGbm();
        var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(trainer);
        var trainedModelWithPreproc = trainingPipeline.Fit(this.AllData); //Fit the pipleline on all the preloaded data

        //Save the model            
        string modelSaveFilePath = "modelPipeline.zip";            
        mlContext.Model.Save(trainedModelWithPreproc, dataSplit.TrainSet.Schema, modelSaveFilePath);

        //Now Load back the model and test it
        // Define trained model schemas
        DataViewSchema modelSchema;
        ITransformer allInOneModel = mlContext.Model.Load(modelSaveFilePath, out modelSchema);

        List<TreatmentObservation> testingData = null;
        //Load testing data here...(code not included)

        var observations = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(testingData);
                               
        var engine = this.mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TreatmentObservation, Prediction_MultiLabel>(allInOneModel);  //Create the prediction engine

        foreach (TreatmentObservation observation in testingData)
        {
            var predicted = engine.Predict(observation);
            uint label_value = predicted.PredictedLabel;

            string label_key;
            //How to get back the Key from the predicted value?

        }
```

And here is the class used to make predictions in the above example:

```
// Class used to capture predictions.
public class Prediction_MultiLabel
{
    // Original label.
    public uint Label { get; set; }

    // Predicted label from the trainer.
    public uint PredictedLabel { get; set; }

}
```

So my question is: How can I reverse the mapping when making predictions using a stored and loaded model?

I have looked at examples such as this one: [ML.NET example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.conversionsextensionscatalog.mapvalue?view=ml-dotnet) but these examples do not use a stored model. They construct and then use a pipeline directly. I need to know how to reverse the mapping from a stored model. I am not an expert with ML.NET, so please excuse if there is some ignorance in my question!

Answer (score 1):

Worryingly, after two days I have received no suggested solutions from the ML.NET community. But I managed to put together a solution using this [ML.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.conversionsextensionscatalog.mapvaluetokey?view=ml-dotnet) help post. The code shown in the Question Statement above needs to be amended using the following pattern:

```
//First create an explicit map for mapping keys to values. The values will be the index of the items in the array. 
        var lookupData = new[] {
            new LookupMap { Key = "Banana" },
            new LookupMap { Key = "Apple" },
            new LookupMap { Key = "Orange"  },
            new LookupMap { Key = "Melon" },
        };

        //Convert to IDataView
        var lookupIdvMap = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(lookupData);
        
        //Now create the pipeline, with an explicit keyData Map using the above mapping
        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "Label", nameof(Fruit.Name), keyData: lookupIdvMap)                                                        
                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(Fruit.Color), nameof(Fruit.Diameter), nameof(Fruit.Weight)));
```

Now train the model using this pipeline, then save it (example code is in the question statement above).

Next, load the stored model back for testing, and create a prediction engine. Again, example code is in the question statement above. Once you have done that, you can make a prediction and get the Name instead of the Value, as follows:

```
//Here is an example of how you make a prediction:
        //In this case 'observation' is an instance of the type 'Fruit'
        var predicted = engine.Predict(observation);
        
        //Compare the observed and predicted name of the fruit
        string obs_Name = observation.Name;  //this is the observed value
        string pred_Name = lookupData[predicted.PredictedLabel - 1].Key;  //this is the predicted value.
```

The type LookupMap is a simple class defined as follows:

```
// Type for the IDataView that will be serving as the map
public class LookupMap
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```